# Custom PrintFormatting for GSON

Tags: java, gson

I'm having some trouble with GSON in regards to printing. GSON has two options when it comes to printing.

1. Pretty Printing
2. Compact Printing

I intend to use a modified form of Pretty Printing and even though the [documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#compact-vs-pretty-printing-for-json-output-format) says **JsonPrintFormatter** is the class which is used to modify the output format. I can't find that class in the GSON repository!

Any ideas on why this is the case or anyway I can modify the GSON printing?
Apart from that, any libraries used to modify spacing or formatting of JSON in the Java language would also be helpful.

Pretty Print:

```
    {
  "classname": "something",
  "type": "object",
  "version": 1,
  "properties": [
    {
      "propertyname": "something1",
      "type": "String",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "propertyname": "something2",
      "type": "Date",
      "length": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Compact Print:

```
{"classname":"something","type":"object","version":1,"properties":[{"propertyname":"something1","type":"String","length":255},{"propertyname":"something2","type":"Date","length":10}]}
```

My Print Style:

```
{
  "classname": "something",
  "type": "object",
  "version": 1,
  "properties": [
    {"propertyname": "something1","type": "String","length": 255},
    {"propertyname": "something2","type": "Date","length": 10}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this part clarify that you can't? `If you would like to use the Pretty Print feature, you must configure your Gson instance using the GsonBuilder. The JsonFormatter is not exposed through our public API, so the client is unable to configure the default print settings/margins for the JSON output.`

Comment: I remember reading that but if there is a way using third-party library or something!

Comment: I believe there is always a way (didnt know a lib though), but what is your usecase to require such specific styling of the json?

Comment: Long-Story Short : POJO to JSON.
Plenty of field names (properties)
Want to enable them to be more readable to the end user as shown in the above "My Print Style"

Imo pretty print is very readable and I've also converted it to YAML ( highly readable ) but wanted to ask on Stackoverflow before taking my final decision on discarding this task as it's a very minor change but huge effort.

Comment: I'm certain it's possible with Regex to find and replace the new lines before *{"* with null

Comment: I will add a function to make this possible tonight, fun exercise

Comment: You are adding it GSON i bet..or maybe a Regex find and replace! 
Keep us posted for sure m8! I found a regex way to do this but not 100% working.

Comment: The regex way. I'm afraid that interacting with Gson lib will make things unnecessary complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's just work in progress for now, but this should do the trick for strings with **only one** array. Will look into to making it more stable and able to handle more complex structures.

```
  private static String reformat(String og){
    String reformattable = og;
    String[] parts = reformattable.split("\\[",2);
    String arrayPart = parts[1];
    String arrayOnly = arrayPart.split("]",2)[0];
    reformattable = arrayOnly.replaceAll("\\{\n","{");
    reformattable = reformattable.replaceAll("\",\n", "\\\",");
    reformattable = reformattable.replaceAll(" +"," ");
    reformattable = reformattable.replaceAll("\\{ ","   {");
    reformattable = reformattable.replaceAll("\n }","}");

    return og.replace(arrayOnly,reformattable);
}
```

Result should look like this (at least for my simple class):

```
{
 "classname": "test",
 "properties": [
   {"propertyname": "1", "length": 1},
   {"propertyname": "1", "length": 1}
 ]
}
```

Comment: I can accept this as a Answer because I can get the size of the array at run time( that is splitting up)! Thank You Stefan! :) Kudos!

Comment: @AbuBakarKhan: Be careful about the pitfalls with this solution! It breaks, in a lot of cases, for example if one of the values contains `"["`.